# Changing scale of working area

Tags: interface

**I want to squeeze NLA editor and Dope Sheet on Y axis to fit more objects in one screen.**

For example in VSE this can be done via <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>MMB</kbd> and dragging in prefered direction. Same thing in NLA only works for X axis or stretching timeline. In Graph Editor it works in both ways, but doesn't affect list of objects, so still lots of scrolling.

Another thing I tried, was pressing NumPad's <kbd>-</kbd> while hovering over the interface. In some parts of it font resizes well (like Render or Object tab), but not in NLA - it just hides all rollouts.

Comment: My first though is to just create additional layouts using the dropdown at the top of the Blender screen, then once named and customised switching between them.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the Y Axis to be smaller you need to make the Text/Font smaller.

You could reduce the *Display Scale* under the *User Preferences* > *Interface*.

[image: Rescale]

However, this will affect all unsizable text in Blender.